# .toggle does not show an already hidden div, but it hides a displayed one. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, toggle

i'm trying to make a hidden div show on toggle, but I'm having no luck. The opposite works (if I put display: inline, it is hidden when I click the button). I'm a beginner at JQuery so I might be doing something very wrong. Here's the code:

```
<style>

.boxx {display: none;}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("ggg").toggle(300);
  });
});
</script>

<center>

<button>click here</button><br>
<ggg>
<div class="boxx">show this text</div>
</ggg>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works - https://jsfiddle.net/76gfvspt/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it doesn't with the element already hidden https://jsfiddle.net/eompL041/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to toggle the class `.boxx` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".boxx").toggle(300);
  });
});
```